# Hibernate Envers Revert data to a version

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-envers

We are using Hibernate envers to store historical revisions of the data, there is a requirement to revert data to a certain revision. As we are using the Version column to use the optimistic locking approach, when I try to save data from the previous revision I get a `StaleObjectException`. Is there any way to force Hibernate to store data from previous revision?

Comment: Very good question. Can you show us how you're doing it? Trying to load the revision and then saving it? copying from the revision to the actual object?

Comment: I am trying to load the revision and saving it using the merge method of javax.persistence.EntityManager.

Comment: Go through the blog. This may help. http://encodo.com/en/blogs.php?entry_id=22

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's an awesome question. I didn't find anything like that in the envers documentation but I'm sure it's a common issue. As a workaround  you could set the attributes on the desired object revision (in a constructor for instance)

Comment: It is a painful workaround, but look like there is no other alternative.